# Why does `git merge origin` work some of the times?

Tags: git

Instead of doing `git merge origin/branch` I like to do `git merge origin`. Omitting the branch name makes automating and creating aliases a bit simpler.

However `git merge origin` only works for some repositories:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
$ git pull origin
Already up-to-date.
$ git merge origin
Already up-to-date.
```

For other repos there is an error:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
$ git pull origin
Already up-to-date.
$ git merge origin
merge: origin - not something we can merge
```

**Note that the statement `git pull origin` works for both repositories.**

---

Both repositories or on the same system (so running the same version of git). I've examined the `.git/config` and it looks similar for both repos.

It works for

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.jasny/obfuscated-repo-1.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

It does not work for

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:legalthings/iam.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Why does this work in some cases and not in others?

---

For the repo where it's not working, `git rev-parse origin` gives an error:

```
git rev-parse origin
origin
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]
```

For the other repository I'm getting a commit hash.

Comment: Can you run `git rev-parse origin` in either?

Comment: No I can't. It gives an error in the repository where `git merge origin` doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work in 1 of 2 or neither?

Comment: I only works for the one where merge origin is working. On the git where merge origin is failing rev-parse is also failing.

Comment: I don't know the exact criteria of when you'll have it vs. when you won't, but the issue here is that you're missing your `HEAD` ref in the one repo, though you can set it manually via [`git remote set-head $remote $branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html). How did you clone the one repo vs. the other?

Comment: I think (but not 100% sure) that I cloned the repository where it is working from origin. The one where it isn't working, I created locally and than pushed (the initial commit) to origin.

Comment: @Whymarrh Great, that works. Can you put this in an answer, so I can accept and close this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `git merge origin` you are implicitly saying `git merge origin/HEAD`, where `origin/HEAD` is the default branch on your remote. The `HEAD` reference will get set when you run `git clone $repo`.

If your remote does not have a `HEAD` reference, you created the repository locally and pushed it to the remote, in which case Git will not know what the default branch is (and `git fetch origin` will not set it). You can manually set the `HEAD` ref for the remote via:<sup>[[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html)</sup>

```
git remote set-head origin $branch
```

where `$branch` is the name of the branch that you want to set as the default branch for that remote.